# Custom URI Scheme for application

Tags: windows, uri

I am creating a custom uri for my application. I wanted to know if there are any rules on the name of URI .. ie. can i use myApp_1.0 as an uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got the answer, URI schemes can only contain letters, digits, plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-"). also the URI is case insensitive, but it is recommended to use lower case only. 
More details can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme